# Date not displaying in category post

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I am not able to get the date to display for posts listed in a category using [catlist] tag. I use the parameter 'date=yes'. The time displays, but not the date. I have checked the list-category-posts/list_cat_posts.php and found the 'get_the_time' function, but cannot figure out how to get the date to display, not the time??

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_time()` takes the same format as the PHP [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date) function for its parameter. Thus, `get_the_time('F d, Y')` would produce `January 09, 2012` for today.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I am using the category post plug-in by Fernando Briano. His code gets the date format form the wordpress installation configuration. e.g. return  ' - ' . get_the_time($atts['dateformat'], $single); The problem is that it shows the time of the post not the date of the post. When I change the line to get_the_date it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at either the README file included on the plugin or in the [plugin's page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) on WordPress.org, you can find this is one of the parameters:

> **dateformat** - Format of the date output. Default is
>   `get_option('date_format')`. Check
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time for possible
>   formats.

Try using this instead of hardcoding the format into the list_cat_posts.php file. This will be overwritten once the plugin is updated.